# Find maximum value and indices of a maximum without using max built in functions

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, matrix

Like the title says, I'm trying to find the max value and location of the argument(s) without using any variation of the built in max functions.

I was able to piece this together for a basic `np.array`, but I'm having difficulty translating it into a matrix ... I think because of how it is indexed.

Here's what I have for the `np.array`:

```
a = np.array((1,2,2,3,4,3,2,1,4,3))

def argmax(x):
    maximum = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] > maximum: maximum = x[i]
    pos = np.argwhere(x == maximum)[0][0]
    return(print('The maximum value of the array is', maximum, 'and is located at index', pos))

argmax(a)
```

The maximum value of the array is 4 and is located at index 4.

I'm trying to create something similar for any size matrix without using built in max functions. Can someone help me with the function and help me understand the difference in indexing between a basic array and a matrix?

Comment: Can't you keep track of the `i` along with the `maximum` while iterating (and a column `j` if needed)?  That `argwhere` looks like a lot of extra work.  Think of this array as a list or list of lists.  In fact when iterating like this, it's faster to work with a list of lists.

Comment: Are your arrays 2-D at most or higher dimensions are possible?

Comment: Also, do you want a location of random max or all of them if max happens multiple times? Does your array include all non-negative values?

Comment: @hpaulj. I've posted a fairly general answer. I think that is definitely simpler to work with an array because you can use masking.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the quick replies! These are all 2-D arrays. I'd prefer all locations of the max if it occurs multiple times. No negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works for 1d arrays and 2d arrays:**

```
import numpy as np
import math

matrix = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
print(matrix)
# Important
matrix = np.atleast_2d(matrix)
# set maximum to -inf
maximum = -math.inf
# Search maximum
for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        maximum = matrix[i][j] if matrix[i][j] > maximum else maximum

# More than 1 maximum, take the first one?
pos = np.argwhere(matrix == maximum)[0]
print(
    f"The maximum value of the array is: {maximum}, located at: row {pos[0]}, column {pos[1]}"
)
```

**Outputs:**

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
The maximum value of the array is: 19, located at: row 3, column 4
```

Comment: This was perfect! Just so I understands, j in range loops thru the columns and i in range loops thru the rows?

Comment: @smcconn5 Yes, j for columns, i for rows

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it for **ANY shape and dimensions** array (it assumes values are non-negative since you initialize maximum with 0 and returns the first incidence of maximum only as you did in your original answer. Of course you can easily change them):

```
def argmax(x):
    maximum = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(x.reshape(-1)):
        if v > maximum: 
            maximum = v
            pos = i
    print('The maximum value of the array is', maximum, 'and is located at index', np.unravel_index(pos, x.shape))

argmax(a)
```

Example:

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(3,4))
#[[7 6 2 6]
# [7 2 0 5]
# [4 0 8 7]]
```

output:

```
The maximum value of the array is 8 and is located at index (2, 2)
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`. Did you mean to print outside the function?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That is true. Did not even notice that from OP's code. I assumed that is the output they want but really return is irrelevant. Editing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to find the maxima along a given axis. Otherwise, do `np.unravel_index(argmax(a.ravel()), a.shape)`.

First let's define a function that steps along the given dimension and keeps track of both the maxima and the indices at which they occur:

```
def argmax(a, axis):
    # index
    cur = [slice(None) for _ in range(a.ndim)]
    cur[axis] = 0

    # trackers
    val = a[tuple(index)]
    ind = np.zeros(val.shape, dtype=int)

    # loop
    for i in range(1, a.shape[axis]):
        index[axis] = i
        v = a[tuple(index)]
        mask = v > val
        val[mask] = v[mask]
        ind[mask] = i
    return ind
```

This returns the index along `axis`. If you want to get the other indices, do something like

```
all_indices = list(np.indices(a.shape))
all_indices[axis] = ind
all_indices = tuple(all indices)
```

Or alternatively,

```
all_indices = [slice(None) for _ range(a.ndim)]
all_indices[axis] = ind
all_indices = tuple(all indices)
```

This function skips a couple of corner cases, like when `a.shape[axis] == 0` and `a.ndim == 0`, but you can easily handle them with a simple preliminary test.

You can also special-case `axis=None` with a recursive call as shown in the beginning of the answer.

If you want to allow multiple axes simultaneously, swap them all to the end, and reshape them into a single axis. So a hybrid of the `axis=None` and normal processing.